# Path planning without move_base - just using aruco_tag relative pose

Tags: ros, path-planning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to calculate a trajectory based on the information I have:

- aruco_tag relative position and orientation (relative to **camera_link** of my robot)

I don't want to use any information from */map* and my fixed_frame should be **base_footprint** . Is it possible to do? Path planning without using any information from */map* ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412097/path-planning-without-move_base---just-using-aruco_tag-relative-pose/) by [alperenkeser](https://answers.ros.org/users/118101/alperenkeser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2023-02-11**:
Of course it "is possible". Are you trying to drop `move_base` completely, or only create your own planner for use inside move_base? Are we talking about a local_planner or a global_planner?

**Comment by [alperenkeser](https://answers.ros.org/users/118101/alperenkeser/) on 2023-02-13**:
Thanks for the reply. I would like to do it without *move_base* if it's possible. I could not find any tutorials or examples for a path planning algorithm without move_base and with the goal pose is given relative to something like *camera_link* or *base_footprint*, not *map*. Because I am trying to do docking using a camera-aruco tag setup and I want to plan a precise path to my goal, aruco tag. If I take the aruco tag's pose with respect to map, it would be less accurate.

I tried to create my own planner also but I cannot understand how could one do so without using *move_base*. I believe I am talking about both global_planner and a local_planner because I want to create a path to my goal and then I want to navigate through that path BUT my priority is creating a path first. I could deal with navigating it later.

Again, usage of *move_base* is OK for me if it is going to be easier since I am not experienced in ROS :) Main issue is **creating a path between camera_link and aruco_tag**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a basic approach to implementing a solution without using move_base:

"No map" implies you intend to do relative navigation in the robot's frame. For 2D navigation, this means that the goal information you have at each step is: "my goal is at this distance and at this yaw angle." Very important: these values are assumed to be in the `base_link` frame.

If your sensor reading gives you the goal is in some other frame, you need to transform that sensor-goal to your robot's `base_link` frame before you use it.

Then you calculate a Twist message which will move the robot closer to the goal, and publish the message to `/cmd_vel`. You repeat this whole cycle over and over until the robot is "close enough" (or until the robot can't move forward for some reason.)

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2023-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alperenkeser](https://answers.ros.org/users/118101/alperenkeser/) on 2023-02-15**:
I understood the idea better now. But as far as I understand, your method is like a controller depending on the data coming from my goal's pose (distance and yaw). So it is like a visual servoing? I was hoping more like a trajectory planning kind of method because during the motion of my robot, aruco tag (my goal) could get out of the camera frame easily. But still, thank you very much for your guidance.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2023-02-16**:
If you want to pre-plan a path, then you must have a map. And to issue commands to follow a path, you must have some way to estimate your robot's position on that map.